# Issue with multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-sleep

I am facing a problem in Thread .Here is my code

```
private void CustomBrightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    creed = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            final JFrame jfmae = new JFrame("Set BrightNess");
            JLabel jla = new JLabel("!@#$");

            jfmae.add(jla, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jfmae.setSize(180, 180);

            jfmae.addMouseListener(new Mymos());
            jfmae.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                    jfmae.dispose();
                }
            });
            jfmae.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    creed.start();
}

class Mymos extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        try {
            creed.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        Bigh2MousePressed(evt);
    }

    private void Bigh2MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("dsds");
    }
}
```

**CustomBrightActionPerformed**

is a method of another class that deals with Action Event and `Mymos` is inner class .The problem is that I am sleeping `creed Thread` but my main thread is also sleeping for 3 seconds.Why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are invoking [`sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) on main thread,

[`sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) is `static` method you are just using its Thread's instance (creed) to call it which is discouraged, It sleeps the `Thread` in which this method is being called

if you want to pause creed thread then you need to execute [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) from its `run()` method

Comment: One question .if i do some operations in  Bigh2MousePressed and if there is some delay then will it pause Main Thread Excecution also?

Comment: if it is being called on the same Thread then yes, if it is asynchronous call in new Thread, then it will return right away to main thread and it will perform operation on another thread

Comment: I tried Thread.sleep() from creed's run method ,but still it is pausing Main Thread

Comment: did you remove call to `creed.sleep(3000);` ?

Comment: damn I didn't .Sorry for that.